# how to clear modals in ionic angular todo example

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-bootstrap, ionic-framework

I've noticed that in the ionic todo app example the stale/old todo information remains on the modal if I cancel the modal and open it back up again.  What's the best place to clear/reset the old modal data so that it always has fresh blank fields after I cancel or submit the modal form fields?

Should I null or clear the task object somehwere? Reset the fields manually on close and create?  Add a handler to some sort of on hide event?

Here's the angular/ionic example:

http://ionicframework.com/docs/guide/building.html

and a relevant snippet of code

```
 // Called when the form is submitted
  $scope.createTask = function(task) {
    $scope.tasks.push({
      title: task.title
    });
    $scope.taskModal.hide();
    task.title = "";
  };

  // Open our new task modal
  $scope.newTask = function() {
    $scope.taskModal.show();
  };

  // Close the new task modal
  $scope.closeNewTask = function() {
    $scope.taskModal.hide();
  };
```

and the modal

```
<div class="modal">

<!-- Modal header bar -->
<ion-header-bar class="bar-secondary">
  <h1 class="title">New Task</h1>
  <button class="button button-clear button-positive" ng-click="closeNewTask()">Cancel</button>
</ion-header-bar>

<!-- Modal content area -->
<ion-content>

  <form ng-submit="createTask(task)">
    <div class="list">
      <label class="item item-input">
        <input type="text" placeholder="What do you need to do?" ng-model="task.title">
      </label>
    </div>
    <div class="padding">
      <button type="submit" class="button button-block button-positive">Create Task</button>
    </div>
  </form>

</ion-content>
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I've had the same problem. I first tried to clear my form data by clearing the model-object upon closing my modal window, just like you, but that only worked for when I submitted the form, it seems. When cancelling, it doesn't work! (Even if you explicitly clear the object before hiding the popup, it will not work)

I eventually fixed it by doing this:

```
$scope.newTask = function() {
   $scope.task = {};
   $scope.taskModal.show();
};
```

This way, every time the window is loaded, you clear the model. So the trick is not to do it when submitting data, but when opening the modal window. That did it for me at least.

Btw, I also needed an edit function for this same modal window, so I do this:

```
$scope.editTask = function(task) {
   $scope.task = task;
   $scope.taskModal.show();
};
```

Answer (score 0):

The accepted answer is definitely correct but there is another way to achieve the same goal.

```
// Execute action on hide modal
$scope.$on('modal.hidden', function() {
  // Execute action
  $scope.task = {};
});
```